# Outlook received emails rule based on string list?

Tags: python, string, list, email, outlook

Can I make somehow a rule which deletes a received e-mail, if the subject of the e-mail **does not contain** a word (string)?

I want to determine somehow a word list for that. If the subject does not contain any element of the word list -> delete the e-mail.

If I open outlook rule wizard, I can add words, but only one by one, so it is slow. I have 1000+ words.

Is there any soulition for that?

I am familiar with python.

Comment: You could write a `VBA` macro as event handler for incoming mails as explained [here](https://www.tachytelic.net/2017/10/how-to-run-a-vba-macro-when-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook/). Store the words once at Outlook startup time in a `VBA Collection` in your own `Application_Startup` macro. It might be time-consuming to loop through a long collection for every mail. Store the most frequent words early on.

Comment: An alternative way is to delete incoming mails by default. Only mails which are matched by given words are kept. This can be done using Outlook rules. In extended mode, you can add a list of words rather than one-by-one. Make sure you test this properly.

Comment: How can I enable extended mode in Outlook? Is it free or not? I tried to search for "extended mode outlook" but i couldnt find for that mode.

Comment: If you create a rule in Outlook, you have a simplified mode with few options by default. However, there is an `extended` button on the rule creation dialog which opens a dialog with more option. I do not know how this button is named in other languages. Enhanced? Detailed?

Comment: It is called `advanced options`as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59).

Comment: The problem: Inside the advanced options I select "with specified word in the body", after that I click on specified words, and I can only add words one by one, I cannot add list.

Comment: I am sorry that I sent you down a dead end. Writing a VBA script still appears to be the simplest path. You could use VBA to create a rule. It might be better in terms of performance to rely on built-in rule execution than on VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a VBA script or a COM add-in for Outlook to implement that.